# iOS Xcode Development with Segues full screen

Tags: ios, segue, gesture

I am new to iOS native development and have been struggling for a few days to understand some of the segue concepts. I have tried googling for that answer but I must not be using the terminology Apple has created for this.

I have inherited some code and I am trying to move from the login screen of my app to my first page in full screen. It moves to that page and gives the user that ability to swipe down and go back to the login screen. This is not the functionality that I want. I want to use a button to go back and not gesture functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you created a "Present Modally" segue, select that Segue and, in the Attributes Inspector pane:

[image]

Select `Full Screen` from the **Presentation** drop-down.